# Response is not correct

Tags: c#

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetExternalAgencyById/{id}")]
public DTOExternalAngencies GetExternalAgencyById(int id)
{
    DTOExternalAngencies agency = _businessEntityService.GetAgenciesById(id);

    if (agency == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return agency;
}
```

If anyone accesses the id that not present in the database table that time it will show 404 response to user. Not found

Answer (score 1):

The code correctly checks if the `agency` variable is `null`, indicating that no agency was found for the given `id`. In such a case, the code returns a `NotFound()` response, which is an HTTP 404 status code.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetExternalAgencyById/{id}")]
public ActionResult<DTOExternalAngencies> GetExternalAgencyById(int id)
{
    DTOExternalAngencies agency = _businessEntityService.GetAgenciesById(id);
    if (agency == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return agency;
}
```

In the updated code, the return type of the method is changed to `ActionResult<DTOExternalAngencies>`, which allows you to return different types of HTTP responses. Returning `NotFound()` will result in a 404 response if the agency is not found.

Make sure you have the necessary using statements at the top of your file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

This will enable the `NotFound()` method and other related HTTP response methods.